# CakePHP how to change select box to checkbox ?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have two tables store and users.They have one to one relation.After bake store I get user list in a select box.I want to make all selection to check box because farther I want to select multiple users for one store.Now I just need to convert this select box to check box.

I have tried

```
<?php 
 echo $this->Form->input('mad_stores_id');
?>
```

To

```
<?php 
 echo $this->Form->checkbox('mad_stores_id');
?>
```

But this is giving me only one check box.I need to display all option which have given in selection box.

Here is the controller find methods

```
$users = $this->UserStoreSelection->Users->find('list',array('fields' => array('id','username')));
```

How can I show all select option in check box ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're relationship is base on One to One, then you shouldn't allow end users to select multiple users for store. That would be a hasMany relationship.

Anyway, here you go

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('mad_stores_id', array(
'multiple' => 'multiple')); ?>
```

Edit: if its multiple checkboxed yo want, then its the following:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('mad_stores_id', array(
    'multiple' => 'checkbox')); ?>
```

Comment: Here relation is not the issue.Here I just want to see list selection box to check box.

Comment: As posted. Returns a multi selectable list for me.